# Keep track of User-to-User Application Requests ( invites )

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface, request

I'm working on new project and want to allow Facebook invites.

I need to throttle invites though, as I'm focused on Product and not Scalability right now.

I'm trying to grasp how I can do this with the current Facebook system....

Using the Requests Dialog:

- I can specify a max_invites parameter
- The actual Invites are handled through their Javascript API, so I can only use a callback function to alert my server

I really want to ensure that my small group of users can only invite one or two people right now.  Until I scale, I can't risk having an extra 100 total accounts.  Even if I drop the requests to "1", all someone needs to do is pop-open another request dialog and they can invite more people.

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you instead ask the users to send a link to a person that they would like to invite, which could contain a referral or beta / access key? You could then limit the number of keys / links that each user can generate.

E.g:

```
Refer a friend to the service:

<input box for e-mail> <send button>
```

Friend receives:

```
XYZ wants you to join FunNewSite.Org

Click this link to register http://FunNewSite.org/register.php?key=14usdijf8923u5
```

Comment: I have an email invite tool, I wanted to extend it with a Facebook Invite.

However... your comment sparked an idea.  I could possibly use the Facebook SEND button.

Comment: Would it be possible to allow / get the user to send the link via. Facebook? This would solve your problem of having a fixed number of invites.